# How can I add the value of 2 cards that I drew, into the card value that i just draw, in a game of BlackJack

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Blackjack {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cardValue; /* card value is from 2 to 11 */
    int MaxCard = 50;
    Stack < Integer > Player1 = new Stack < Integer > ();
    Stack < Integer > Addition = new Stack < Integer > ();
    Stack < Integer > Dealer = new Stack < Integer > ();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    Random r = new Random();

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mitchell's blackjack program!");

    for (int a = 1; a <= 2; a++) { // Start's the game by assigning 2 cards each, to the players
      int Player1draw = 2 + r.nextInt(11);
      int Dealerdraw = 2 + r.nextInt(11);
      //System.out.print("\nPushing in " + Player1draw + " to Player 1."); - used for checking
      Player1.push(Player1draw);
      //System.out.print("\nPushing in " + Dealerdraw + " to Dealer."); - used for checking
      Dealer.push(Dealerdraw);
    }

    Integer pop1 = (int) Player1.pop();
    System.out.print("\nYou get a " + pop1);
    Integer pop2 = (int) Player1.pop();
    System.out.print(" and " + pop2);

    int sum = pop1 + pop2;

    System.out.print("\nYour total is " + sum);

    if (sum > 21) {
      System.out.print("\nYou LOST! ");
      System.exit(0);
    }

    Integer pop3 = (int) Dealer.pop();
    System.out.print("\nThe dealer has a " + pop3 + " showing, and a hidden card.\n");
    Integer pop4 = (int) Dealer.pop();
    System.out.print("\nHis total is hidden, too.\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < MaxCard; i++) {
      System.out.print("\nWould you like to \"hit\" or \"stay\"? ");
      input = keyboard.next();

      if (input.equals("hit")) {
        int draw2 = 2 + r.nextInt(11); // draw -> 'hit' for another card
        int sum3 = sum + draw2;
        System.out.print("\nYou drew a " + draw2);
        System.out.print("\nYour total is " + (sum3) + ".");

        if ((sum + draw2) > 21) {
          System.out.print("\nThe Dealer WON and you LOST!");
          System.exit(0);
        }
      } else if (input.equals("stay")) {
        System.out.print("\nOkay, dealer's turn.");
        System.out.print("\nHis hidden card was a " + pop4);

        int sum2 = pop3 + pop4;
        System.out.print("\nHis total was " + sum2);

        if (sum2 > 21) {
          System.out.print("\nThe Dealer LOST and you WON!");
          System.exit(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So when the code runs, what it does is that it will draw 2 cards for Player1 (both of the card is shown) and the dealer(1 of the card is shown). It will then display the total number of points player1 has. So after i press hit, to draw another card, it calculates the total value just fine because it sums up the current drawn card value into the previous 2 card.

Now the problem is, how can I code it so whenever I type the 'hit' button again it will than add up the previous 3 cards and the newly drawn card?

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;
for(Integer card : Player1)
   sum += card;

if(sum > 21) system.err.println("Over 21; you lost");
```

Looking for something like that... ?